# Why does the second replace segue to the detail view controller alwayse crash?

Tags: ios5, replace, crash, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I use the splitViewController for a iPad program. In the master view, which is a tableviewController, a lists of photo name will be show. When you click one of the photo name, the photo will be show in the detail view.

Now the problem is, when you click a photo the first time, the photo will be show correctly; but when you select a photo in the table in the second time, the program will crash!

> **My code**
>
> In the storyboard, I construct a replace segue from the master viewController to the detailView Controller. In the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: of master view controller, I write:
>   **[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Photo Show" sender:self];**
>
> In the prepareForSegue:sender:, I write:
>   **[segue.destinationViewController setCurrentPhotoInfo:self.currentPhoto];**
>
> In the detailViewController, I write codes in the setCurrentPhotoInfo as follows:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[self.imageView setImage: image];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

> **The crash information**

When the program crash, I got the crash in [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Photo Show" sender:self]; the crash information is:
    **[PhotoShowViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6c9eae0.**

To debug the problem, I write codes to observe the destination view controller address in In the prepareForSegue:

```
id last = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
id destination = segue.destinationViewController;
```

To my surprise, the **last** is different with the **destination**! I thought they should be the same.
More surprisely, when you complete the first segue and click the photo table to go into the second segue, you will find the last and destination all changed: destination change to a new address, and the last is equal to the **old destination**!

The crash address "0x6c9eae0" is just the **old last** address.

Why is this happen? I am confused.